Movie where pet monsters had to eat dirt or mud in order to survive
I remember watching a movie when I was a kid (early to mid 1990's), where either a kid or a group of kids discover a group of monsters, or are given them by an old man.  It turns out that either the old man that gave them is evil, or that an old man is after them for some reason, and the monsters start getting sick because they need food.  The kid/s end up giving them over to keep them alive.  However, they somehow steal them back.
In the end it turns out that they could eat dirt or mud (or something that looked like dirt) to get sustenance.
I think one of the monsters was blue.  Also, I think the monsters were puppets or animatronics, rather than cgi.  Also, the monsters were smaller, maybe the size of a jack Russell terrier or smaller.

Important info:

Live Action
Early to mid 1990's
American, in English, in color
I think I watched it either on TV or rented it

It is not:

Prehysteria

